# Why does the color conversion from RGB to HSV produce corrupt images?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

Im working on filtering out certain colors of images, but am stuck when it comes to working with the hsv/hsl colorspaces. If i try to convert a Image read with matplotlib to HSV using `cv2.Color(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)` the resulting image has messed up color just like this: 
[image]

In my understanding, the Image should be displayed just like the original 
[image].

Is this correct or does the mistake lie within my limited understanding of color spaces?

I have tried also reading the image using opencv and then converting for BGR to HSV, which brought different, but still defect images. Also i converted the image to uint8 using `image = (image * 255).round().astype(np.uint8)`, still did not work

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import numpy as np
image = mpimg.imread("Screenshots/vlcsnap-2019-07-22-08h42m14s251.png")
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
hls = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HLS)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(hls)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(hsv)
```

Besides im also getting the following warnign when running the code:
"Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers)."

Comment: try passing `cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV` instead, opencv loads images which are RGB in colour order BGR.

Comment: Not familiar with matplotlib, but does it require the same formats as OpenCV? OpenCV by default stores images in BGR format. Furthermore does the plt.imshow require any flags to take an HSV image and display it normally?

Comment: @EdChum OP used matplotlib to read it which is BGR. The problem is that `imshow` is for displaying `RGB`, `RGBA` and `Greyscale` images in matplotlib. And the image passed is HSV. So the resulting image is a possible result of it.

Comment: @api55 yes that would be a problem, what are you trying to achieve here @lorenzpr?

Comment: What does “In my understanding, the Image should be displayed just like the original image” mean? Can you show your original image in addition to the HSV images inline in the post, so we can compare them and help understand your concerns without having to follow any potentially dangerous external links?

Comment: I have now added a link to the original image as requested, and regarding your comments, i have already tried using BGR2HSV which did not help. @api55 this might not be the case as matplotib displays images converted from RGB to BGR correctly.

Comment: im sorry @rob3c im am  new to this platform, thats why the links were the first option to show images. While i do not quite understand what frightens you about regular imgur links i will try to find out how you can show images inline in the post

Comment: @rob3c well the problem seems to be that i need at least 10 reputaion to post images which i dont have yet..

Comment: @lorenzpr Forgot rep limit for images. Luckily api55 edited to add them inline incl the new original. You still haven't answered my question about what "...displayed just like the original image" means? What are you expecting by "just like"? In any case, the answer by api55 has all you need. The hue (H) channel is special, since it represents degrees around a color circle instead of a linear range like S and V. So for `uint8`, `RGB2HSV` generates 0-180 (half of 360 deg to fit under 255), and for the `float32` that `mpimg.imread` loaded from the png, 0-360 - thus the clipping using `imshow`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the [documentation of `imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html):

> (M, N): an image with scalar data. The data is visualized using a
>   colormap.
>
> (M, N, 3): an image with RGB values (0-1 float or 0-255
>   int).
>
> (M, N, 4): an image with RGBA values (0-1 float or 0-255 int),
>   i.e. including transparency.

This already tells you that whatever matrix of 3 channels you give it (like HSV), it will taken as RGB image. That means, that whatever number is in H it will be taken as R and so on. So Hue values will be the red ones, Saturation values the green ones and value ones will be blue.

The warning you mentioned call my attention and I decided to test it, since I normally do not use `matplotlib` to load/show images. First thing I notice is that the images are type `float32` and are from 0-1 when I used:

```
image = mpimg.imread("imagePath.png")
```

This is ok, and it is the same for OpenCV float32 images.

Now, if you read the documentation of [cvtColor](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.6/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab) and check the [color conversion](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.6/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html) you will see that when the image is type float32 the ranges are:

```
H :[0-360]
S :[0-1.]
V :[0-1.]
```

So this means that most of the values of the first channel of the image will be above 1. and then it will go over the range for float for the function imshow (0-1) which will clip it and then be 1.

As I said before, this image will be interpreted as RGB; therefore, the Hue channel will be the Red channel, and most of the values are max so most of your image will be a tone of red. The green areas are due to big saturation (close to max). However since it is where it is like white, I would say you are displaying HLS and it is the L channel at max.

Now it comes to the question, what are you expecting to be the result? HSV color space will always show you quite a different thing from the original, everything depends on the colors, but small changes such as more or less saturated will give you greener images....

In any case, if you want to show something more reasonable, divide the first channel by 360 which will scale it to be from 0-1. as the other 2 channels. However the green parts won't dissappear but it will look less red.

Comment: I thought the resulting image would have to be the exact same looking, just in another color space and was confused a lot as to why it did not work how I wanted, but to be honest i just messed  up all the Things here and did not even know that matplotlib does display images only as RGB. .Thanks a Lot for clearing up my confusion with your great explanation.

Comment: @lorenzpr thats why StackOverflow is for :) clearing doubts. My recommendation, always read  the documentation of the functions. It usually give you big hints of what could be wrong. BTW, you could take one channel like `h = hsv[:,:,0]` and display it as a greyscale image but with a [colormap of your choice](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html). There is even one to represent the hue colorwheel.

Answer (score 4):

There's in important consequence of the Hue (H) channel being a continuous color circle that you should keep in mind when visualizing HSV conversions. That kind of blockiness is unavoidable, even when you fix the clipping due to not rescaling the 0-360 H channel to 0.0-1.0 for plotting as a float32 with matplotlib.

Unlike the linear scale of the Saturation (S) and Value (V) channels, the min and max values of the H channel are actually adjacent values of red on the color circle. Due to sharp transitions between 0 and either 255 or 1.0 in what is actually similarly redish parts of the original image, you'll often see harsh, blocky areas in whatever channel represents H.

You haven't actually posted your original image, but what looks like a screenshot from a matplotlib plot, so I can't reproduce your effect exactly. However, to see the effect, look at just the H channel by itself with your original and I think you'll see what I mean:

```
H, S, V = cv2.split(hsv)
# here's the opencv way to see it
cv2.imshow('H', H)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Notice the blocky transitions where very light and very dark areas are right next to each other, even though there are smooth red variations there in the original image.

You're using matplotlib, which expects RGB images. So Hue is shown in Red, Saturation in green, and Value in Blue. Everywhere you're seeing those non-red blocks, it's where Hue is close to min 0.0, and everywhere you're seeing normal (for HSV) orange/yellow/white/etc, it's where Hue is closer to max 1.0. The clipping due to not normalizing the 0-360 H channel to 0.0-1.0 exaggerates the problem, but it'll still be there after fixing that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me understand, as mentioned im a beginner and was confused by all of the different factors at play here. And also sorry for not posting the original image, forgot to do that